# Cognitive Services Speech voice change doesn't work

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services

I am able to make WebChat working with the speech services, and it recognizes and replies correctly (in Chrome) with an italian voice, but that's a wobbly male voice.
I am trying to use the neural italian voice, i.e. ElsaNeural, but when I try to set it like below it always use the male voice.
What is the correct way to get the high-quality voice to speak in Webchat/Chrome?

```
            window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
                directLine: dl,
                selectVoice: 'it-IT-ElsaNeural', //short name of neural italian voice
                webSpeechPonyfillFactory, //passing this to enable speech services
                locale: 'it-IT',
                language: 'it-IT',
                styleSet // Passing 'styleSet' when rendering Web Chat
            }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

Comment: Seems this is a bug that still unfixed. Other users have raised a ticket here : https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2221

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have two issues that are blocking you.

1. The `selectVoice` property takes a function (reference [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/ff726defdb9729f7af4eba0f1311f12825ba83d5/packages/component/src/hooks/useVoiceSelector.js)). Simply passing a string value will result in an error. Your code can either return one value, regardless, or you can use a ternary to provide a default voice:

```js
selectVoice: ( voices, activity ) => voices.find( ( { name } ) => /ElsaNeural/iu.test( name ) )
```

or

```js
selectVoice: ( voices, activity ) =>
  activity.locale === 'it-IT' ?
    voices.find( ( { name } ) => /ElsaNeural/iu.test( name ) )
    :
    voices.find( ( { name } ) => /ElsaNeural/iu.test( name ) )
    || voices.find( ( { name } ) => /ElsaNeural/iu.test( name ) ),
```

2. You should double check that the region your CS Speech subscription is located in supports using neural voices. I tested using neural voices in both `westus` and `westus2`. As expected from the list of [supported regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/regions#standard-and-neural-voices), testing `westus` failed while `westus2` was able to convert TTS with the above "ElsaNeural" voice.

When following the above, I was able to successfully use the provided neural voices.

Hope of help!